# Whenever I change my desktop background, it changes my laptop's background as well

Tags: windows, desktop

I recently got a new laptop. They're both Windows, so I used the same Microsoft account to log into both. When I turned my laptop on, it had the same background as my desktop, so I changed it, only to go back to my desktop and see that it changed to my laptop's new background. How can I keep the backgrounds separate?

Comment: Oh, so this is what happened to me. I just bought a new laptop, with a preset background from the producer. Soon my desktop had gotten the same background all by itself. I thought I was going insane. But they are linked by the Microsoft account. Phew.

Answer (score 26):

To disable the synchronization of the certain settings to computers with your Microsoft account (on Windows 8):

1. Open the Charms bar, hit Settings, then choose *Change PC settings*.
2. On the left, click *OneDrive*.
3. Again on the left, click *Sync settings*.
4. In the main area, disable settings you don't want to sync.

The one that controls the desktop background is *Appearance*, the second one under the *Personalization settings* header. If you don't want any settings synced, disable the very top setting, *Sync your settings on this PC*.

On Windows 10:

1. Open the Settings app from the Start menu.
2. Click *Accounts*.
3. On the left, click *Sync your settings*.

The one that controls the desktop background is *Theme* here ([source](http://www.howtogeek.com/222110/understanding-the-new-sync-settings-in-windows-10/)).

Changes to these settings take effect immediately.

Comment: Thanks the other information I have found never mentioned your solution.

Comment: What's weird to me is that a new Windows 10 laptop, which asked me to pick a desktop background during setup, then reached into my old Windows 8.1 PC and interfered with my settings there without warning me at all. I find it incredibly disconcerting. I thought I owned my old PC, but it seems like I'm just borrowing it from Microsoft.